# Redirect users with ID questions to reddit

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, identify

[reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue](http://reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue)

Specifically designed for identifying movies or whatnot. What are your thoughts? I believe this is going to work because the site has many people active and also there will be many people watching for new questions and are willing to dig for movies that you are describing/talking about.

So basically I request we change the text in the "This question was closed" to the above link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nah. Like 'em or hate 'em, the concensus of opinion was (and seems to remain) that [identify-this-movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-movie) questions are on-topic on Movies:SE.

> [Discussion on identification questions](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/discussion-on-identification-questions)

We don't close questions simply for being story-ident, we close them for being ***badly asked*** story-ident. When that happens, what we want is for the asker to improve them, not go somewhere else.